# SVG tag and SVG image don't load when i use parcel build

Tags: javascript, html, svg, github-pages, parceljs

I have a problem with my site, once i build the project with parcel, when i host the site with github pages some SVG imported Images (for example as background image in css) or some SVG tags (in html file) don't load.

**For example the following SVG is not loaded:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" id= "clickPad1" height="210px" width="210px" class="" style="position: absolute; top:-5px; left:-5px;>
      <circle id="circleClick" r ="5" fill="white"></circle>
</svg>
```

**Instead the following is loaded:**

```
<svg style="position: fixed; top:35px; left:36px" width="20" height="20">
   <circle r="2" fill="black">
     <animate attributeName="cx" values="2;8;3;5;4;2" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
     <animate attributeName="cy" values="2;3;2;8;5;2" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
   </circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first svg the circle is missing the attributes cx and cy. Now, I don't know the context, but make sure that the fill color sticks out. I changed it to black. The style attribute in `<svg>` was missing a quote-mark ("). The attributes with and height don't need the length type (px).

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="clickPad1" height="210" width="210" style="position: absolute; top:-5px; left:-5px;">
      <circle id="circleClick" cx="20" cy="20" r="5" fill="black"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the code still not work.. The problem is in parcel. We ran
`npx parcel build src/prj.html --dist-dir ./public --public-url ./` and some svg tags and files didn't work.
Instead with 
`npx parcel src/prj.html --no-cache` the Svgs work.